# how to refresh web page after executing stuffs in controller method on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, page-refresh

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I using drop down menu on one page and I observe it. In that it will go to controller method and I need to reload after executing things on that particular controller method. How can I do this on rails ?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting at the end of your action in your controller `redirect_to` to the same path of the controller/ action.